# Pass a runnable to a Thread - Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to run a `Runnable` object in three kinds of `threads`. The `Swing EDT`, the `current thread` (which is the thread that created the object) and the `main thread`.

So far I've come this step:

```
public class MyExecutor implements Executor {

    public final static int SWING_MAIN_THREAD = 0;
    public final static int MAIN_THREAD = 1;
    public final static int RUNNING_THREAD = 2;

    private int threadType = -1;

    public MyExecutor (int threadType) {
        this.threadType = threadType;
    }

    @Override 
    public void execute(Runnable runnable) {
        switch(threadType) {
            case SWING_MAIN_THREAD:
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(runnable);
                break;
            case MAIN_THREAD:
                // pass the runnable to the main thread
                // if main thread is the EDT, pass the runnable to the EDT
                // if main thread is a "normal" thread, pass the runnable to it
                break;
            case RUNNING_THREAD:
                // pass  the runnable to the thread that created this object
                break;
        }
    }
```

Now I'm stuck on the `MainThread` and `RunningThread` case because I can't find a way to pass the `runnable` object to the respective `Thread`. I know how to get the `Thread` but I don't see any methods to pass a `runnable` object to it.

Comment: You pass it in the Thread constructor.

Comment: @GregS But the thread is already running... this is the problem

Comment: What is the "main" thread?  There really isn't one.  Do you mean the currently executing thread?

Comment: @markspace I mean the first thread that was created at start-up. The thread that started the program/software.

Comment: OK, see below.  There's no "main" thread stored away so you can use it.  Does not exist.

Comment: I probably should ask what your goal is here.  The desire to do these things is kind of odd.  What are you hoping to accomplish?

Comment: Use Thread.currentThread in the constructor to know which thread created it? And save the Thread.currentThread inside main methid to know the main thread of your app. But what you want to do? It's strange

Comment: Yes, you could save the thread manually.  But that's a weird concept.  I think the OP needs to discuss what he's actually trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main reason you can use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` is that the EDT has a task queue that its processing loop picks off and runs tasks from, and `invokeLater` simply posts the given task to that queue.

Most threads do not have a processing loop or a task queue, though, so you can't post tasks to arbitrary threads. You can code in such a loop for your threads, of course.

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass an Object to a "thread that created this object", but you can pass it to a thread that invoked the execute() method, which would be the normal definition of the currently running thread

```
        case RUNNING_THREAD:
            // pass  the runnable to the thread that created this object
            runnable.run();
            break;
```

The "main" thread doesn't exist as a concept in Java, sorry, you can't do that one.  (What I mean is the main thread doesn't get stored specially so you can access it.  There's a main startup thread of course, but it's not special.)

Comment: See above.  You have no access to it specially.  The system doesn't store it so you can use it later.  It's just a normal thread that runs, the same as all other threads.

Comment: I think with "main thread" he refer to the thread created by jvm to launch the application

Comment: What if that thread has encountered an error or simply exited?

Comment: @MarcoAcierno Yes, markspace knows that. But still, there is no special accessor for getting that thread. Unless what you want to do is iterate through all the threads and look for one named `main`. But any Tom, Dick, and Harry can create a thread named `main`.

Comment: He could save it in a variable inside the main method as i said in comments. I'm not saying that's a good thing to do because what he want to do is not possible with "standard" threads that's why i upvoted your answer :)

Comment: @MarcoAcierno If the OP wants to go to that kind of trouble, they could just code in a processing loop and task queue. ;-)

Comment: @Chris Jester-Young: yes, everyone can name a thread `"main"` and, just for completeness, everyone can give the main thread a different name. @Marco Acierno: you can save a reference to the main thread but what for? Having a reference to a `Thread` does not offer any way of forcing the thread to execute a particular `Runnable`.